# If I perform a clean installation of Windows 10 over an existing Windows 10 installation, will the OS automatically activate when started?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license

I realise the question is a bit of a mouthful, I'll try to clarify here.

I have Windows 10 (**Education Edition**) on my SSD, and a fast mechanical drive for data.

If I create a bootable Windows 10 USB, wipe the SSD, and install Windows 10 Education edition again on the SSD, will the OS automatically activate again due to the fact I haven't made any hardware changes?

Comment: It depends if your version uses an digital entitlement.  Worst case you activate the installation by phone

Comment: If you type `Reset PC` in the startmenu, you can reinstall windows as if it was fresh (have the option to keep your files) and it will keep your windows installation activated no matter what. But the SSD will not be completely wiped. Note: your files on your DATA drive will never be touched.

Comment: How old is the computer? Any more now the key is stored on the motherboard for your particular version of windows. Therefore the computer applies the key for you. Which is why you don't see those stickers with the product key on the computer any more.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys. I took the jump and did it. Fortunately, it worked fine. My computer is a custom built PC with Windows 10 Education installed. When I booted the USB stick, I wiped the SSD, installed Windows in its place and when it ran for the first time, it automatically activated. So all good :)